# SpringMVC, using two contexts and two dispatchers for Rest Service and normal contents

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

In my SpringMVC project configuration, I have a `RootContextConfiguration` and other two context configuration files for rest services and normal requests namely; `RestServletContextConfiguration` and `WebServletContextConfiguration`.

And, I'm bootstrapping the application as in the following code.

```
public class Bootstrap implements WebApplicationInitializer
{

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext container) throws ServletException
    {
        container.getServletRegistration("default").addMapping("/resource/*");

        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext rootContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        rootContext.register(RootContextConfiguration.class);
        container.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(rootContext));

        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext restContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        restContext.register(RestServletContextConfiguration.class);
        DispatcherServlet restServlet = new DispatcherServlet(restContext);
        restServlet.setDispatchOptionsRequest(true);
        ServletRegistration.Dynamic springRestDispatcher = container.addServlet("springRestDispatcher", restServlet);
        springRestDispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        springRestDispatcher.addMapping("/api/*");

        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext webContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        webContext.register(WebServletContextConfiguration.class);
        DispatcherServlet webServlet = new DispatcherServlet(webContext);
        ServletRegistration.Dynamic springWebDispatcher = container.addServlet("springWebDispatcher", webServlet );
        springWebDispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(2);
        springWebDispatcher.setMultipartConfig(new MultipartConfigElement(null, 20_971_520L, 41_943_040L, 512_000));
        springWebDispatcher.addMapping("/*");
    }
}
```

I need **/api/cars** to resolve to

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/cars")
class CarRestController{}
```

And **/cars** to resolve to

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/cars")
class CarController{}
```

However, deployment fails because of ambiguous mapping. If I change the mapping of `CarRestController` to `@RequestMapping('/api/cars')` then I can access that controller with the path **/api/api/cars** (Note the double **api** prefix). But what I want is to be able to access the `CarRestController` with **/api/cars**.

What should I do to achieve my goal?. Highly appreciate your help.

Comment: Is rest controller located in same package as mvc controller? And what is your component scan settings for any of contexts?

Comment: **RootContext**-> `@ComponentScan(basePackages = "xxx.spring",excludeFilters = {@ComponentScan.Filter(Controller.class), @ComponentScan.Filter(RestController.class)})`.  **RestServletContext**-> @ComponentScan(basePackages = {"xxx.spring"},useDefaultFilters = false, includeFilters = @ComponentScan.Filter(RestController.class)). **WebServletContext**-> @ComponentScan(basePackages = {"xxx.spring"},useDefaultFilters = false,includeFilters = @ComponentScan.Filter(RestController.class))

Answer (score 0):

Why you dont put mapping @RequestMapping on your method ?

For example

```
@RestController
public class YourClass {
@RequestMapping("/car")
public String yourMethod() {  }
}
```

Comment: I have number of mapped methods in each controller. Therefore, I have annotated the base path for the controller at class level. Then, should I decide to change the base path for all the methods inside a controller, I don't have to change  many places.